# If a potentiometer is basically a voltage divider, why are they made in different values?

Tags: potentiometer

I was taught that rheostats are current based devices, while potentiometers are voltage based. I can see why rhostats come in different values (eg making variable loads of different magnitudes), but why make potentioeters of various sizes if all pots of a given taper will return the same potential at, say, the 12 O'clock position? Or, given two points of different potentials, pots specify a point between the two. I never got very far in school, so I greatly appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: Because different impedances.

Comment: Rheostats and potentiometers are *resistance* based. They are passive devices.  A rheostat will happily regulate voltage: google for a very common circuit schematic for a variable voltage regulator.

Comment: Perhaps my use of "based" was a bit loose, but my point was: for times when adjusting how much current flows is the agenda,call on the rheostat. When it's time to express yourself relative to the potentials of 2 other points, hook up with the potentiometer. Sure, there is some overlap in their behavior, but overall they're from different camps. The first answer shows a pot setting a light's brightness. But the MVP here is current. The lower part of the pot has

Comment: little influence, and can be ignored. That leaves us with a rheostat doing most of the job. The first answer also makes mention of a large piece of control gear, where the potentiometer is buffered, thereby drawing nearly no current. This time the name of the game is voltage. This is also the part where I lost my way. All I could see was how all the different pots were acting the same. So let me thank all of you for your explanations. Each take helped me strengthen my grasp of the material

Answer (score 4):

It is true to say that the output voltage from similar potentiometers at the same position with different overall resistances will be the same **into an infinite impedance**. That is the same as saying **"if we draw absolutely no current out of it"**.

Now often that is the case (or so nearly the case that it makes no difference). Let's say that we're using it to set a parameter on a large piece of control gear. It is almost certain that the first thing that control gear will do is to **buffer** the signal - that is to pass it to an amplifier that doesn't amplify it, but draws nearly no current and makes a higher current version of the signal available. In this case, it really doesn't matter much what the overall value of the potentiometer is, and you'll likely find it is whatever is easiest and cheapest to manufacture.

However, let's say we chose not to do that. Take a look at the circuit below:

[image: Never EVER build this!]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuPyxu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's say that we're trying to vary the brightness of a 100 Ohm light bulb powered by 12V. We could try to do this as in the schematic. Let's say that the potentiometer is at half-way. We're expecting 6V across the light bulb, which gives a light bulb current of 6 / 100 = 60mA. However, what we actually get is different. The current for the light bulb has to flow through the "top half" of the potentiometer - 5kOhms and then splits itself between the bottom 5kOhms and the 100 Ohm light bulb. The next drawing shows this redrawn as separate resistors to show you what's going on.

[image: Expansion of potentiometer into two fixed resistors]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foi8UD.png)</sup>

So let's try and calculate the voltage at the across the lamp, and hence the current through it. We're going to use the potential divider equation but with the bottom resistance calculated using the [resistors in parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits) formula, calculated taking R2 and the light bulb in parallel. This resistance = \$ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{5000}+\frac{1}{100}}\$ = 98 Ohms  (or thereabouts).

So now, we do our potential divider calculation:

\$V_{out} = V_{in} \left(\frac{98}{98+5000}\right) = 12 \left(\frac{98}{98+5000}\right) = 0.23 Volts !!!\$

That's way off what we wanted, and our current (which we wanted to be 60mA) is now 0.23/100 = 2.3mA. So what happened? Well, the equations I used show it, but effectively the current that we pulled into our load partially "shorted out" the bottom half of the potentiometer.

If you repeat this equation with a 1 Meg Ohm load, you will see that it makes almost no difference and the output voltage is pretty much bang on 6V. Larger resistors pull less current and so load the output less, leaving the output voltage exactly where we wanted it. However, you can't just say "let's make all our lightbulbs 1 Meg Ohm resistance", or the voltages required to get any power out of them would be enormous. Remember that \$ Power = \frac{V^2}{R}\$, so for the same voltage, the higher the resistance of the load, the less power it draws.

Another thing to notice from this is that when you're calculating resistors in parallel, the answer is always smaller than the smallest resistor in the set - this is handy when checking results yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The *open circuit* output of a voltage divider is only a function of the ratio of the two resistors.  Both resistors can be scaled by the same arbitrary factor and the open circuit output voltage will remain the same.

**However:**

The load on the source is is inversely proportional to the total resistance.  This is the current flowing thru the pot, having nothing to do with where the tap is set to.  A 10 kΩ pot and a 10 Ω pot across a 12 V supply will both give you a linearly adjustable output from 0 to 12 V at the same pot positions.  However, even without anything connected to the output of each pot, the first will draw 1.2 mA from the supply and dissipate 14.4 mW, while the second will draw 1.2 A from the supply and 14.4 W.

The output impedance is the parallel combination of the two resistances.  At either extreme, the output impedance is 0, but when the pot is set to the middle it is 1/4 of the pot value.  A 10 kΩ pot across a 12 V supply would put out 6 V with 2.5 kΩ impedance at its center setting.  That's just fine going into many A/Ds, for example, but no good if you need to draw significant current from this 6 V.  For example, with 1 mA drawn from the 6 V pot output, the voltage would drop by (1 mA)(2.5 kΩ) = 2.5 V, resulting in only 3.5 V.  If you shorted the 6 V output to ground, you'd only get 2.4 mA.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the application you might have 0.1 volt or 250 across the pot element, you might be willing to accept 1W of power burned in the element, or maybe 10uW is about as much as you're willing to accept.

Your output resistance looking into the wiper varies from 0\$\Omega\$ at either end to R/4 \$\Omega\$ for a pot element resistance of R\$\Omega\$.

For example, a battery powered gadget, 5V across the element, 0-5V from the wiper. You might be willing to accept a 50uA current draw- so you pick a 100K pot. Now the resistance looking into the wiper will vary from 0 to 25K. If that's a problem (say it causes linearity issues) you might have to put a buffer amplifier on the wiper.

As another example, you have a 400VDC focus voltage adjustment for a CRT. You might not be too concerned about power consumption since it's mains-powered, but the series of insulated pots you want to use is only good for 500mW. From Watt's law, that means the lowest resistance you could pick is 320K, but usually pots come in 1-5-2-10-50-20 sequence, so you could pick 500K. You could also pick 1M or 2M or 5M, but the voltage output from the wiper will not be as 'stiff' so it will change more with loading. Trade-offs.

As yet another example, you might be adjusting offset on a thermocouple amplifier and have +/-2mV of adjustment range, so you might pick a very low resistance pot, say 100 ohms. If that's not low enough you might put a 10 ohm resistor in parallel with the element.

One thing about pot tolerances is that they are typically pretty crummy. Not a huge deal if you have stiff voltage sources on each end (such as our 5V and 0V example) but if they form part of a resistor chain as in a bridge arrangement, then a +/-20% tolerance may be a bother. If you can tolerate more resistance looking into the wiper then you can pick a higher value pot and shunt it with a 1% resistor so the tolerance of the combined element/resistor is much better. For example a 200 ohm 20% tolerance pot in parallel with a 10 ohm 1% resistor will have a tolerance on the combined parallel resistance of about +/-2%.